# iterator for function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iterator, function-pointers

I'm a beginner in C++ and am having trouble with the iterator for function pointers right now. Here's what I've got so far.

I'm using Visual Studio.

```
typedef int(*IntFunPointer)(int);
for (IntFunPointer::iterator it = f.begin(); it != f.end(); ++it) {
//some code
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Sorry I should be more clear.

Here is the question:

Implement a function

```
void fill_with_values(int[] a, int size, IntFunPointer f)
```

that sets the ith element of the array to f(i). Here IntFunPointer is a typedef for a
pointer to a function that consumes an int and yields an int.

So what I was trying to do is to iterate through the array and set each element to f(i) accordingly. But it doesn't work out well...

Edit:

Comment: What if `f`? Why aren't you just using `auto`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `IntFunPointer`  does not have any nested type called `iterator`. How do you expect to use `IntFunPointer::iterator` as a type?

Comment: I'm really new to the concept and thanks for pointing that out. Does that mean iterators cannot be used for function pointers?

Comment: @sayalmondbutter It means the very question is nonsense... My toaster doesn't have a peanut butter slot. Does that mean peanut butter can't be used with my toaster? How will I make peanut butter toast?

Comment: You will have to explain why you think this *should* work, in order for other people to understand your understanding well enough to explain what's wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I see the real question...

Implementing `fill_with_values` is very simple.

```
void fill_with_values(int a[] int size, IntFunPointer f)
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   {
      a[i] = f(i);
   }
}
```

What you are doing here is not iterating over the function pointer. You are executing the code in the `for` loop `size` times. You are calling the function `f` in every iteration of the `for` loop and filling the contents of `a[i]` in the iteration.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine, but for some reasons it is throwing a lot of errors while compiling

Comment: @sayalmondbutter, I edited the way `a` is declared in the function. Try again.

Comment: Now it works. Do you mind explaining a bit why the difference? Thanks!

Comment: @sayalmondbutter, `int [] a` is not a valid declaration. `int a[]` is a valid declaration. Can't explain why it is invalid. It just is. `int a[]`, on the other hand says `a` is an array of `int`s whose size is not specified.

Comment: @sayalmondbutter R Sahu was in a Java mood, I guess.